# Remove select all from combobox WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have combobox in WPF application that when the user clicks on it, it selects all the text. How can I change the behavior of this to when the user clicks it just set the typing cursor like a normal textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" />
```

Comment: I think he wants to have it editable, but he does not want the text in the `TextBox` (within the EditTemplate) to be selected when he clicks on it, but he wants the cursor to be positioned before/behind the character that he clicked.

Comment: Thanks gehho, this is what I need! Any idea!

Answer (score 0):

According to Reflector, the `ComboBox` code contains this:

```
private static void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = (ComboBox) sender;
    if ((!e.Handled && box.IsEditable) && (box.EditableTextBoxSite != null))
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource == box)
        {
            box.EditableTextBoxSite.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.OriginalSource == box.EditableTextBoxSite)
        {
            box.EditableTextBoxSite.SelectAll(); // <==
        }
    }
}
```

This method is registered for the `GotFocus` event in the static constructor using the `EventManager`:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ComboBox), UIElement.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ComboBox.OnGotFocus));
```

So, I think you can only change that behavior by deriving a custom control from `ComboBox` and override this event registration by your own method which replaces the call to `SelectAll()` with another method which sets the caret to the correct position. However, I do not know how to set the caret to the click position. You might have to use Reflector on the TextBox to find that...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I had to solve similar issue.
It's quite tricky, but the way I solved is to set IsEditable to false/true from code, at the same time I set the focus on TextBox.

Not the pretties way but does the job.